# How can I prevent certain process from being swapped?

Tags: swap

How can I prevent something like SSH from being swapped, and always keep it in the RAM? I already set `swappiness` to `1`, but SSH is still very slow, so I suspect it's being swapped out.

Comment: You should check the list of processes actually using the swap memory to see and make sure which one is the culprit, for instance, you could install `smem` (python based, a bit slow but you should not need it very often). It is likely that SSH itself is not swapped out, it's really small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you cannot prevent a single process from swapping and only the global parameter `vm.swappiness` can be used to control the swap behaviour.
With `cgroups` it is possible to specify different `swappiness` for the processes that are attached to a specific `cgroup`.

So, you would have to create a separate `cgroup` for your SSHD and give it a different `swappiness`.

I think your problem is caused by something else. `swap` does free up RAM, but if you access processes that have swapped out memory, that memory is read from disk and put into RAM again. So when accessing a process with swapped memory there is only *ramp-up* performance bump.
If you experience steady swap-out/swap-in issues, you either have too less memory or a run-away process eating up your RAM and puts your system under memory pressure.